# Calculate the difference between last two elements in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to calculate the difference `income` `total` between last two months (`_id`).

`{income[1]?.total}` always get me a fixed number: `900`.

How to calculate the `total` difference between last two elements?

Note: `res.data` already sorted by `_id`.

```
const [income, setIncome] = useState([]);
  const [perc, setPerc] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getIncome = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income");
        const sort = res.data.sort((x, y) => x._id - y._id)
        setIncome(sort);
        setPerc((res.data[1].total * 100) / res.data[0].total - 100);
        console.log(sort);
      } catch {}
    };
    getIncome();
  }, []);

return(
  <div>{income[1]?.total} $</div>
)
```

this is my console.dev:

```
0: {_id: 6, total: 448}
1: {_id: 7, total: 900}
2: {_id: 8, total: 100}
3: {_id: 9, total: 700}
4: {_id: 10, total: 990}
5: {_id: 11, total: 20}
6: {_id: 12, total: 20}
```

Comment: Can't you just do Math.abs(income[income.length - 1].total - income[income.length - 2].total) (if you want the difference with the sign you can remove the abs). Of course you have to check that at least two element exist for this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i get your problem right 
you must get 2 last object of your array to do so you can write:

```
// last object of array
const arrayLen = sort.length - 1;
```

then you can get the second last one as well and then compare the two values.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [income, setIncome] = React.useState([]);
  const [diff, setDiff] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getIncome = async () => {
      try {
        const res = [
          { _id: 6, total: 448 },
          { _id: 7, total: 900 },
          { _id: 8, total: 100 },
          { _id: 9, total: 700 },
          { _id: 10, total: 990 },
          { _id: 11, total: 20 },
          { _id: 12, total: 20 }
        ];
        const sort = res.sort((x, y) => x._id - y._id);
        setIncome(sort);
        const arrayLen = sort.length - 1;
        setDiff(Math.abs(sort[arrayLen].total - sort[arrayLen - 1].total));
      } catch {}
    };
    getIncome();
  }, []);

  return <div>{diff} $</div>;
}
```

`Math.abs` is used to change the negative number to positive.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [difference, setDifference] = useState(0); 

//... then later...

if(sort.length > 1){
    setDifference(sort[sort.length - 1].total - sort[sort.length - 2].total);
}

//...then in your JSX...

<div>{difference}</div>
```

This will give you the difference between the last two elements' total props in the sort array.